# Why and how do species diverge in the same region?

Tags: evolution, speciation

I want to begin by saying thatt I'm not a student of biology, so I apologize if this is an obvious question. My question is about species in general, but I'll be focusing on hominins since I'm more familiar with them.

I've been reading about human evolution, and it seems that at some point 3 different genera coexisted (Austrolopithecus, Paranthropus, and Homo) somewhat close to each other. My question is twofold:

1. Why did this three species diverge? One partial answer is specializing to a niche; e.g. the Paranthropus can eat less nutrient rich food, but there doesn't seem to be a concrete niche the Homo are filling compared to the Austrolopithecus. For some birds, it seems even less clear if they are filling a niche; e.g. sometimes just a couple of colors, feathers, or songs change.
2. How did they maintained the divergence? At least based on Homo Sapiens behavior with other relatives, I'd believe that these hominins wouldn't mind procreating with each other. It seems to me that they all live in a relatively small area, at least when considering that they are not sedentary and have hundred of thousands of years to move to cycle around all Africa, so I'd think there were plenty of opportunities to mix. Why didn't they mix until they got completely homogenized? Thinking of birds again, at least for those that don't have a very specialized mating ritual, I'd have expected all of them to mix so that there is at most one subspecies of bird per niche, but this is not at all the case.

Comment: There might be different reasons I guess. In general, there is a machanism for speciation in the same region, namely sympatric speciation. However, I doupt this is relevant for hominins. But, even if these species lived roughly in the same regions, there can become geographically isolated, for example by newly formed river, etc.